# Como executar um Script utilizando AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho um form em uma página "pagina1.php", assim:

```
<form id="form1" action="pagina2.php"
</form>
```

Após executar um função Ajax, eu adiciono o seguinte script dentro desse form com .append():

```
<script id='mp_script'  src="https://www.mercadopago.com.br/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
data-preference-id="9999999">
</script>
```

Só que esse Script não é executado, como faço para executa-lo depois de adicionar ele com Ajax?

Obs. Não posso adicionar esse script de outra maneira a não ser com AJAX, pois o atributo "data-preference-id" vai mudar dependendo do que o usuário seleciona na tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `document.createElement` para criar o `<script>` e em seguida inseri-lo no corpo da página:

```js
function createScript(src, attrs = {}) {
  // Criamos o `<script>`:
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  
  // Adicionamos os atributos customizados que recebemos pelo primeiro parâmetro:
  Object.entries(attrs).forEach(
    ([key, val]) => script.setAttribute(key, val)
  );
  
  // Origem do `<script>`:
  script.src = src;

  // Inserimos o `<script>` na página:
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

createScript('https://lffg-archive.github.io/sopt/alert.js');
```

E para adicionar um atributo customizado ao script criado, basta usar o segundo argumento da função que criamos. Por exemplo:

```js
createScript('https://lffg-archive.github.io/sopt/alert.js', {
  'data-preference': '9999'
});
```

#### Leitura sugerida

- [`Document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement);
- [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild);
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).